# Background sounds get picked up only when I talk by Tascam DR-07X even with low-cut filter

Tags: audio-recording, tascam

In my videos, I am using Low-Cut (High-Pass) filter coming with Tascam DR-07X to eliminate ambient sound such as air conditioning or computer fan noise, etc. but they seem only to be eliminated during my silence, but when I start talking, the background noises get picked up again. Currently, the low-cut Hz is set to 40.

Here is the video where you can clearly see the problem I am talking about:

What do you guys think the problem is, and how can I fix (preferably w/o any software help).

Comment: How are you processing the audio in this clip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The audio processing chain in whatever video editing software you are using has either a "de-noiser" or an "expander" built in. This has the effect of reducing the signal gain when there is little to no signal input detected. Thus, you hear noise when there is dialogue signal but no noise when there is not.

To my ears it sounds a bit harsh, so the de-noising process isn't working particularly well. Your solution to this is to identify the audio processing blocks that are working on your dialogue and tune them to taste. I would reduce the harshness of the expander/denoiser personally, and maybe EQ some of the bottom and top ends of the overall spectrum.

I also note that the dialogue is sounding a little bit like it is 'underwater'. This is often due to lossy audio encoding that is running at a bit rate that is too low. Allocate additional bits to the audio to increase the bitrate. This should reduce the artifacts audible in the dialogue.

Comment: You were right. Your answer helped me realize that I was using the built-in microphone while I thought it was Tascam. I fixed the issue by choosing the right microphone and everything works as expected. The low-cut filter makes wonders.

Comment: hth. glad it works!